# Sentences hard to understand (LLpsI)

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

> Ecce eī in somnō appāruit maestissimus Hector, fīlius Priamī mortuus — sed ***quālis*** erat, ***quantum*** mūtātus ab illō Hectore quī ex tot proeliīs victor redierat!
> Sordidam barbam crīnēsque cruentōs gerēbat et vulnera illa ***quae plūrima circum mūrōs Trōiae*** accēperat. 
> —— *Lingua Latina per se Illustrata: Roma Aeterna*, Ch. 37, L. 92

- What is the accurate meaning of the ***quālis***... ***quantum*** part?
  ("...but how much it was varied from ...!"?)
- Where is the verb for the ***quae***-clause? (I think ***accēperat*** is parallel to ***gerēbat*** and takes ***vulnera illa*** as its object.) What does "most around the walls of Troy" mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Behold, to him appeared in a dream most grieving Hector, the dead son of Priam—but **what** he was, **how much** he had changed from that Hector who had returned the victor from so many battles! He bore a dirty beard and bloody hair and those **many** wounds **that** he had taken **around the walls of Troy**."

1. I understand **sed quālis erat** to mean, liberally translated, "But oh, what he had become!" or "But what a state he was in!"
2. The verb of the **quae**-clause is **accēperat**. Unlike **gerēbat**, **accēperat** is in a subordinate clause.
   **Plūrima** agrees with **quae**, which stands for **vulnera**. Perhaps a better translation, but less parallel with the Latin, would be "…those wounds, most of which he had taken around the walls of Troy." The adjective **plūrima** appears in the subordinate clause but describes **vulnera** from the main clause (via **quae**), because **plūrima** further restricts **vulnera**.